# How to define the map as a constant object, not in a method which will be created again and again

Tags: kotlin

This is my method which used to populate a map, and there's other data will be added in the future.

```
object ConfigurationService {

    fun populateCache(client: RedissonClient): RMap<String, String> {
        val map = client.getMap("map")

        map["k1"] = "v1"
        map["k2"] = "v2"
        ....

        return map
    }
}
```

The problem is, each time when I calling this method in my main function, it will re-create the same map content again and again, is there a way to define it as a constant map object, not in a method.

This is what I did, is that correct?

```
class ConfigurationService(client: RedissonClient) {
        val map = client.getMap("map")

    fun populateCache(): RMap<String, String> {

        map["k1"] = "v1"
        map["k2"] = "v2"
        ....

        return map
    }
}
```

Comment: Currently it is not really constant, you may get a different `Map` instance each time you call `client.getMap("map")`, as this piece of code doesn't know the implementation of `RedissonClient`. Your method here receives that `client` as parameter (could potentially be a different one each time as well). If you could store a constant map, which client should it use?

Comment: @Joffrey I think the client is the same

Comment: In reply to your edit: it's hard to tell what "correct" means for you without a more precise description of what you want to happen. How and when do you expect the cache to be used and to be populated? This is probably what will drive the implementation here.

Comment: @Joffrey I expect the cache populate when I do this in my main function "val map = client.getMap("map")"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to extract the constant part as a property on your object:

```kotlin
object ConfigurationService {

    private val fixedMapContent = mapOf(
        "k1" to "v1",
        "k2" to "v2",
    )

    fun populateCache(client: RedissonClient): RMap<String, String> {
        val map = client.getMap("map")
        map.putAll(fixedMapContent)
        return map
    }
}
```

But I don't think that's what you're looking for.

If the `client` to use is always the same, another option is to inject that client into `ConfigurationService` (which will not be an `object` anymore, you'll need to inject it as well):

```kotlin
class ConfigurationService(private val client: RedissonClient) {

    val cache by lazy {
        val map = client.getMap("map")

        map["k1"] = "v1"
        map["k2"] = "v2"
        ....

        map
    }
}
```

If you want to control when the cache is initially populated (instead of lazily on first access), you can also do this:

```kotlin
class ConfigurationService(client: RedissonClient) {
    
    val cache = client.getMap("map")

    fun populateCache() {
        cache["k1"] = "v1"
        cache["k2"] = "v2"
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, do I need to do " val cache = client.getMap("map")" again in main function when I calling this populateCache() method?

Comment: @Alex No you don't. The `cache` property is available as `configurationService.cache` when you have an instance of `ConfigurationService`. It is updated when you call `configurationService.populateCache()` and then you can just read it as many times as you need.